# Use <f:section name="HeaderAssets" on cached pages in TYPO3 v8.7.32

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I use the following to add some CSS in the template of my custom Extension:

```
<f:section name="HeaderAssets">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="typo3conf/ext/extName/Resources/Public/CSS/filename.css" />
</f:section>
```

This works perfectly fine, if TYPO3 can cache the page. But if you set the Page in TYPO3-BE to exclude from caching, the CSS is not included anymore.

I found this Ticket https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87402, which is resolved, but I still have the problem.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Issue 87402 was closed because the issue was fixed with https://forge.typo3.org/issues/89445. The last one has been fixed 6 months ago but only in the master branch (=> TYPO3 v10). So, in version 8 it is still not working.